# Properties of coefficients of potential in multiconductor systems

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conductors

In multiconductor systems, it is stated that the coefficients of potential have symmetry.

\begin{matrix}\phi _{1}=p_{11}Q_{1}+\cdots +p_{1n}Q_{n}\\\phi _{2}=p_{21}Q_{1}+\cdots +p_{2n}Q_{n}\\\vdots \\\phi _{n}=p_{n1}Q_{1}+\cdots +p_{nn}Q_{n}\end{matrix}
So for the system above, pij = pji, by symmetry (1). In other words,
if a charge Q on conductor j brings conductor i to a potential φ, then the same charge placed on i would bring j to the same potential φ.

Also, potential on conductor_i can be derived in integral form as following,\begin{matrix}\ {\displaystyle \phi _{i}=\sum _{j=1}^{n}{\frac {Q_{j}}{4\pi \epsilon _{0}S_{j}}}\int _{S_{j}}{\frac {f_{j}da_{j}}{R_{ji}}}.}\end{matrix}
where Sj = surface of conductor_j, fj = charge density at a specfic point divided by average density, daj = area element, Rji = the distance from the area-element daj to a particular point ri on conductor i.

Since the integration is independent of surface charge density (2), we can derive pij from the equation above.

Heres my problem. Although they're stated like known facts, I just can't get an intuitive understanding on (1) and (2). I don't understand why coefficients of potential have symmetry, and I don't understand why the result of integration above is independent of surface charge density, since function 'fj' is inside the integral. Am I missing something obvious?